# Make JRuby inherit Java proxy settings

Tags: ruby, http, proxy, jruby, jrubyonrails

I would like to make HTTP requests from Rails code running on top of JRuby.

How can I make it to re-use http.proxyHost, http.proxyPort and http.nonProxyHosts settings, given to JVM running it ?

Answer (score 3):

To pass JVM flags through JRuby, use `-J...`. In this case:

```
jruby -J-Dhttp.proxyHost=foo -J-Dhttp.proxyPort=1234 -J-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="*.bar.com" ...
```

This is explained in JRuby's help text.

```
-J[java option] pass an option on to the JVM (e.g. -J-Xmx512m)
                use --properties to list JRuby properties
                run 'java -help' for a list of other Java options
```

Comment: It will pass the flags to JVM indeed, but Ruby's Net::HTTPClient does not take them into an account...

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Net::HTTPClient, but don't you have to set up proxy in that library as well? From the documentation, it sounds like you have to tinker with `ENV["HTTP_PROXY"]` and `ENV_JAVA["http.proxyHost"]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue.  I found that java or net::http doesn't obey the nonProxyHosts option.   The best way to get around this is to modify the ENV_JAVA settings to account for this.

The steps I took to ensure nonProxyHosts was used were the following:

```
1) JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=192*** -Dhttp.proxyPort=1234 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=local|127.0.0.1"
OR
1) JRUBY_OPTS="-J-Dhttp.proxyHost=192*** -J-Dhttp.proxyPort=1234 -J-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=local|127.0.0.1"
```

Keep in mind that at least for java1.7 the nonProxyHosts should not have quotations see [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/JAVA+Option+%27-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts%27+Does+Not+Work).

Now I find that either net::http or java itself doesn't actually honour the nonProxyHosts option.

However you can get around this by doing the following in JRuby

```
a = URI("http://someurl")
Net::HTTP.new(a).proxy?.should == true
regex = /$#{ENV_JAVA["http.nonProxyHosts"]}/ #dollar needed to behave as expected
if a.hostname.match(regex)
   ENV_JAVA["http.proxyHost"]=nil
end
Net::HTTP.new(a).proxy?.should == false
```

Hope that helps.