# open uri on jruby proxy issues localhost

Tags: jruby, open-uri

I was originally using rsolr to generate and connect to solr cores on my local machine.  This all worked fine in ruby until we moved to jruby.  I now receive a 504 gateway error for localhost http requests. This comes from `Open-uri`. We do have a proxy and I have unset it, set it and used `Net::HTTP::Proxy` to attempt to connect to localhost.

The error I get is:

```
require 'open-uri'
open("http://127.0.0.1:8984/solr/")

OpenURI::HTTPError: 504 Gateway Time-out
  from /Users/adamcryer/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/1.9/open-uri.rb:346:in `open_http'
  from /Users/adamcryer/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/1.9/open-uri.rb:775:in `buffer_open'
  from /Users/adamcryer/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/1.9/open-uri.rb:203:in `open_loop'
  from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1254:in `catch'
  from /Users/adamcryer/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/1.9/open-uri.rb:201:in `open_loop'
  from /Users/adamcryer/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/1.9/open-uri.rb:146:in `open_uri'
  from /Users/adamcryer/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/1.9/open-uri.rb:677:in `open'
  from /Users/adamcryer/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/1.9/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
  from (irb):3:in `evaluate'
  from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1093:in `eval'
  from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1489:in `loop'
  from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1254:in `catch'
  from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1254:in `catch'
  from /Users/adamcryer/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/bin/irb:13:in `(root)'
```

I have also tried aliases for localhost -> 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0 and my actual local ip 192..

Any idea why this is.  Can Open URI in jruby not handle redirects?

**EDIT:** it does connect if the real local IP is used i.e 192.... (but not on localhost, 127.0.0.1):

```
jruby-1.7.4 :013 > open("http://127.0.0.1:8985/solr/")
  OpenURI::HTTPError: 504 Gateway Time-out
    from /Users/adamcryer/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/1.9/open-uri.rb:346:in `open_http'
    from /Users/adamcryer/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/1.9/open-uri.rb:775:in `buffer_open'
    from /Users/adamcryer/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/1.9/open-uri.rb:203:in `open_loop'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1254:in `catch'
    from /Users/adamcryer/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/1.9/open-uri.rb:201:in `open_loop'
    from /Users/adamcryer/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/1.9/open-uri.rb:146:in `open_uri'
    from /Users/adamcryer/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/1.9/open-uri.rb:677:in `open'
    from /Users/adamcryer/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/1.9/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
    from (irb):13:in `evaluate'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1093:in `eval'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1489:in `loop'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1254:in `catch'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1254:in `catch'
    from /Users/adamcryer/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/bin/irb:13:in `(root)'
jruby-1.7.4 :014 > open("http://192.168.2.210:8985/solr/")
 => #<StringIO:0x385715 @status=["200", "OK"], @meta={"content-    type"=>"text/html;charset=UTF-8", "x-cache"=>"MISS from pH-squid", "x-cache-lookup"=>"MISS from pH-squid:3128", "via"=>"1.1 pH-squid:3128 (squid/2.7.STABLE9)", "connection"=>"close"}, @base_uri=#<URI::HTTP:0x2a717ef5 URL:http://192.x.x.x:8985/solr/>>
```

Thanks for any help in advance

**EDIT:**

This is essentially a duplicate of:

[Make JRuby inherit Java proxy settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844505/make-jruby-inherit-java-proxy-settings)

Answer (score 0):

See [Make JRuby inherit Java proxy settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844505/make-jruby-inherit-java-proxy-settings)

Which essentially states:

I have had the same issue. I found that java or net::http doesn't obey the nonProxyHosts option. The best way to get around this is to modify the ENV_JAVA settings to account for this.

The steps I took to ensure nonProxyHosts was used were the following:

```
1) JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=192*** -Dhttp.proxyPort=1234 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=local|127.0.0.1"
OR
1) JRUBY_OPTS="-J-Dhttp.proxyHost=192*** -J-Dhttp.proxyPort=1234 -J-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=local|127.0.0.1"
```

Keep in mind that at least for java1.7 the nonProxyHosts should not have quotations see here.

Now I find that either net::http or java itself doesn't actually honour the nonProxyHosts option.

However you can get around this by doing the following in JRuby

```
a = URI("http://someurl")
Net::HTTP.new(a).proxy?.should == true
regex = /$#{ENV_JAVA["http.nonProxyHosts"]}/ #dollar needed to behave as expected
if a.hostname.match(regex)
  ENV_JAVA["http.proxyHost"]=nil
end
Net::HTTP.new(a).proxy?.should == false
```

Or at least this is the only way I could get it to work